# How to add hash and query params to a url in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hash

I want to add query params and hash to a url from controller without reloading the page.

```
var param [
    query: "abc",
    page : 1
];
$location.url("/project").search(param);
```

This changes the url from **domainname.com** to **domainname.com/project?query=abc&page=1** which is fine but I also want to add div id to the url using hash.
I want my url to be **donainname.com/project?query=abc&page=1#result** . How to achieve this any suggesstion or comments ?  One thing should be taken care of that query params and hash should be added in one go as I have written a function which gets call when url changes otherwise it gets called more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it using [`$location.hash`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#hash)

```
$location.url("/project").search(param).hash('result');
```

Comment: app.run( function($rootScope, $location, $http, $window) { 
 $rootScope.$watch(function() { 
  return $location.url();
 },
 function(a){  
     });  
});  This function gets called when url changes, In your case it will call my function twice.

Comment: You can also set the url by hand using and redirect `window.location`, but then the page would reload, in case you're looking to avoid that.

Comment: ya I don't want to reload the page

Comment: could you host your code somewhere for help with debugging?